# VSTO excel button becomes image after hidding column

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

The following code is in 'onClick' of the button in excel ribbion.
I am using VS15, Office2016.
After I add a button in a cell by following code and then I hide the column, the button moves in the next column(to the right) and when I unhide the column it becomes an image (in its original position and button is in the next cell).

```
        Excel.Range selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Excel.Range;

        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

        ExcelTools.Worksheet vstoSheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(worksheet);

        ExcelTools.Controls.Button button = new ExcelTools.Controls.Button();

        string btnName = "btn" + selection.Row  + "c" + selection.Column;

        button.Text = "+";

        vstoSheet.Controls.AddControl(button, selection.Left, selection.Top, 25, 25, btnName);
```

#### screenshot

[image: Pic]

In pic, where image of button is was the original position of the button

I want the button to be hidden with the column when it is hidden and and stay at is position.Can anyone help me find out what i am doing wrong?